# Android MapView: how to save position/zoom after animateTo and zoom?

Tags: android, position, zooming, android-mapview

Is there anyway I can get some position information for animateTo or current center of the MapView so I can restore it later? Also the same for zoom level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) , see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959833/webview-how-to-preserve-the-users-zoom-settings-across-sessions)´s  GetZoom() and SaveZoom() functions you can use something similar

```
static final  String PREFS_Zoom = "PREFS_Zoom";

 private String zoomlevel;
 private int Default_zoomlevel=100;


 private void GetZoom(){
  try{
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_Zoom,0);
      zoomlevel = settings.getString("zoom_level","");     
   if (zoomlevel.length() >0)   
    Default_zoomlevel = Integer.parseInt(zoomlevel);               
   else
   Default_zoomlevel =100;
  }catch(Exception ex){
   Log.e("******ZOOM ! ", "Exception GetZoom()  ::"+ex.getMessage());          
  }
 }


 private void SaveZoom(){
  try{
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_Zoom,0);            
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();    
   Default_zoomlevel = (int) (mWebView.getScale() *100);
   editor.putString("zoom_level",""+ Default_zoomlevel);   
   editor.commit();
  }catch(Exception ex){
   Log.e("******ZOOM ! ", "Exception SaveZoom()  ::"+ex.getMessage());    
  }
 }
```

UPDATE::

MapView Class has a method [getZoomLevel()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getZoomLevel%28%29) that returns the current zoom level of the map.
for GeoPosition check [getLatitudeSpan()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getLatitudeSpan%28%29) and [getLongitudeSpan()](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html#getLongitudeSpan%28%29) methods

Comment: I am looking at your code, but is there anyway I can get current zoom level of the MapView and geo position(or scroll X, Y) of the map?