# how to preserve zoom and position level in webview android between different pages?

Tags: android, webview, zooming, preserve

I created an app that uses a webview with different url-pages with back and forth arrow buttons.

My problem is that when the user zooms in, in a particular region of the webview and then presses the forth or back button, the new url is loaded with the zoom level reset to default.

How can I preserve the zoom-level and position of the webview, in order to apply it to the new url that will be loaded?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2962708/506879) which will help you preserve the zoom level of your `WebView`.

[This article](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2012/01/preserving-the-state-of-an-android-webview-on-screen-orientation-change/) will guide you through the process of preserving the `WebView's` fine states.

Merging them you'll achieve the desired aspect and behavior.